# Anyway to print a list of all resources loaded in a page using the Net tab in Firebug?

Tags: firebug

I need to get a list of all resources that are required in order for a certain page to load. The Net tab in Firebug has all this info, but I can't find a way to print out the full path (http://domain.com/images/etc) for all of the files.

Does anybody know if this is possible? I know you can right click on each request and select "Copy location", but there's over 100 requests and I'd like to be able to just click once to copy the location for each file.

Comment: You could try using the Live HTTP Headers addon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Firebug FAQ page: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#NetExport